# How to download a directory from an s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I downloaded the aws cli with the macos gui installer:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

And I'm running this command to download the directory from an s3 bucket to local:

```
aws s3 cp s3://macbook-pro-2019-prit/Desktop/pfp/properties/ ./ --recursive
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
rosetta error: /var/db/oah/279281327407104_279281327407104/dcf7796bca04d6b4d944583b3355e7db61ca27505539c35142c439a9dbfe60d0/aws.aot: attachment of code signature supplement failed: 1
zsh: trace trap  aws s3 cp s3://macbook-pro-2019-prit/Desktop/pfp/properties/ . --recursive
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Is aws cli is installed properly? Check with `aws --version`

Answer (score 0):

If these steps doesn’t work, I should you verify just list first (aws s3 ls s3://macbook-pro-2019-prit) and check yours ACL, Policy or others access control on your bucket.

Although I believe that your issue is on your system operation, please confirm that your AWS user has policy with allow list and get to macbook-pro-2019-prit. And reinstall AWS cli.